# Angular directive only works once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple Angular directive but it only renders once.

Successive calls to the template fail to render.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    A. <ui-foo value="1" />
       B. <ui-foo value="2" />
       C. <ui-foo value="'fubar'" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []);
angular.module('ui', [ 'ui.directives'
]).value('ui.config', {});

angular
    .module('ui.directives', [])
    .directive('uiFoo', 
        function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'E',
              scope:{
                  value:'='
              },
              template: '<h1>This is my directive #{{value}}</h1>'
          };
        }
  );
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.directives']);
```

I would expect to see

```
A. This is my directive #1
B. This is my directive #2
C. This is my directive #fubar
```

but I only see the first line.

See my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/354/) for a quick repo

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to close those tags of ui-foo like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   A. <ui-foo value="1"></ui-foo>
   B. <ui-foo value="2"></ui-foo>
   C. <ui-foo value="'fubar'"></ui-foo>
</div>
```

Else, the first directive replaces the other two.

Comment: That is right, angular doesn't like `E` directives being autoclosed.

Comment: doh. I'm thought I tried that but somehow tricked myself and hadn't. Updated and working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleSt1ck5/A8Vgk/358/ . thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to fix this is that you should nest each ui-foo tag into each corresponding controller like as this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="aController">
    A. <ui-foo value="1" />
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="bController">
       B. <ui-foo value="2" />
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="cController">
       C. <ui-foo value="fubar" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: I wouldnt recommend this, since its all against the "Dry"-principle. You would need 3 seperate controllers that do the same thing.